# dotMethods with list object ... combining arguments

Tags: r, list

i am learning R and referring to a book. The code in the book defines a new function and then it has a line -  "args <- list(...)"
i understand that when we define a function with (...) it means that we can pass a varying number of arguments to that function.  does the above line take all the arguments that an user passes to function and then combines them into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not really. It only converts the arguments that were not matched in the function call to the 'args'-list.

```
funtest <- function(a, b, ..., d="junk") { dots<-list(...); print(dots) }
> funtest( 1,2,3,4,5)
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

Only the arguments that were not positionally matched get into the list(..) value. And if the matching were done by name, then it is again only the "left over" arguments that get matched to `...`:

```
> funtest( 1,2,3,a=4,b=5)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

And a bit of advice. Probably not a good idea to use the variable name 'args' since there is also a function named `args`. It's likely that you will confuse either yourself or your readers in the long run:

```
> args(funtest)
function (a, b, ..., d = "junk") 
NULL
```

Comment: thanks. the next line of code say - splom(~datamatrix[, 1:3], lower.panel = function(...){}, upper.panel = upperp) what the purpose of 2nd and 3rd argument? they seem very confusing...does lower.panel = function(...){} mean that we are creating a new function and not defining anything for it? does upper.panel = upperp mean we are calling upperp function but not passing any arguments to that function? appreciate your help

Comment: `lower.panel = function(...){}` would mean what you say, but as for the rest, you have the book and I don't. Those functions were most likely defined earlier in the text. It is possible to call a function just by using its name, so `upperp` would get its function from whattever the defaults were for `upper.panel`. Read the ?splom page.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, and the `...` inherits the names and order of those arguments (if available).

```
> f <- function(...) { return( list(...) ) }
> f(1, 2, apple=3, banana=4)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

$apple
[1] 3

$banana
[1] 4
```

It's useful to write these toy functions and examine the output in this way when you're learning as well.

Comment: thanks to both of you. the next line of code say - splom(~datamatrix[, 1:3], lower.panel = function(...){}, upper.panel = upperp)             what the purpose of 2nd and 3rd argument? they seem very confusing...does lower.panel = function(...){} mean that we are creating a new function and not defining anything for it? does upper.panel = upperp mean we are calling upperp function but not passing any arguments to that function? appreciate your replies...